# Update nested fields in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to update every field of a given type to `T | () => T`. Given the following TypeScript type:

```
type User = {
 first: string;
 last: string;
}
```

Are there any utility types available, which would allow me to map `User` to:

```
{
  first: string | (() => string);
  last: string | (() => string);
}
```

Hope this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: It sadly doesn't

Comment: @omindh It sure does https://stackoverflow.com/a/70928174/5318436

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use mapped type, e.g.

```
type Fn<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] | (() => T[K]);
}

let user!: Fn<User>;
user.first // string | ()=>string
```

If you want to do it on nested fields, you can do it recursively.